# What is the difference between load and assign in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Visit https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/Variable

What is the difference between load and assign methods in Tensorflow.

Answer (score 2):

The `assign` method adds operation to the graph and assignment takes place when this operation executed.

The `load` method doesn't add operations to the graph and just copies value to the variable at the time it called.

Sometimes you want to have assignment in the graph (for examples global step counter) and sometimes you just want to load some value into a variable.